# Can I solve a system of linear equations, in the form Ax = b with A being sparse, using Eigen?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, eigen

I need to convert a MATLAB code into C++, and I'm stuck with this instruction:

```
a = K\F
```

, where `K` is a sparse matrix of size n x n, and `F` is a column vector of size n.

I know it's easy to solve that using the Eigen library - I have tried the `fullPivLu()` method, and I've been able to built a working snippet, using a Matrix and a Vector.

However, my `K` is a `SparseMatrix<double>` (while `F` is a `VectorXd`). My declarations:

```
SparseMatrix<double> K(nec, nec);   
VectorXd F(nec);
```

and it seems that SparseMatrix doesn't have the `fullPivLu()` method, nor the `lu()` one.

I've tried, in fact, these two different approaches, taken from the documentation:

```
//1.
MatrixXd x = K.fullPivLu().solve(F);
//2.
VectorXf x;
K.lu().solve(F, &x);
```

They don't work, because `fullPivLu()` and `lu()` are not members of `'Eigen::SparseMatrix<_Scalar>'`

So, I am asking: **is there a way to solve a system of linear equations (the MATLAB's mldivide, or '\'), using Eigen for C++, with K being a sparse matrix?**

Thank you for any help.

Comment: please, look at the related documentation [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would Eigen::SparseLU work for you?